# Publishing results of pact-verify to pact-broker

Tags: scala, pact

I'm kinda new in pact and I'm trying to make some POC of using pact, but I got stuck on a problem with sending back provider results of test from pact-verify.

Got my pact-broker set localy, with already published pacts from consumer. Afterwards i use:

'sbt "pact-verify --host localhost --port 8081"' with results:

[...]
Attempting to fetch pact from pact broker at: http://localhost:8080/pacts/provider/Provider/consumer/Consumer/latest
[...] ...and all passed tests. (Yes, got broker on 8080, and service on 8081)

Afterwards I can see my Consumer_Provider.xml report in test-reports, but I'm not seeing any results on my pact-broker service.
I've already edited pact.sbt/build.sbt to not use locally stored pacts, and according to documentation it should automatically appear out there since it uses the pact directly from broker.

Am i missing something? Or scala-pact doesn't support such thing? [does it even matter that I'm using scala, or it has nothing to do?]

Thanks in advance.
Marek

Answer (score 0):

Two things spring to mind. The first one is that none of the verification tools will automatically publish the verification without that feature being switched on. You wouldn't want to publish the verification from your local machine for instance - just from the CI machine. Have a look at the documentation or code and see if there is a flag. You'll need to provide the provider version number too.

Secondly, the verification publishing may not have been implemented in the sbt tool yet. I'll check with the JVM Pact author.

Comment: Are you using this implementation? https://github.com/ITV/scala-pact

It's not quite as up to date as the rest of the JVM implementations. I'd suggest raising a feature in their repository, and tagging me in it so I can provide the requirements (@bethesque) This is the more "standard" JVM implementation https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm

Comment: I've got my provider version and name being set. Unfortunatelly I wasn't able to find a flag that enables publishing, so I belive you may be right, and it's not implemented yet. Will give it few more shots anyway.

Do you see any possibility of exporting this result manually to broker? That wouldn't be that bad either.

And ofc you were right, at this moment I am using ITV implementation. As it's POC so far I will stick to it for this moment. Which implementation would you suggest when using in real project? I believe well documented one would be my favorite.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The implementations from https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm are fully featured, and are the ones I'd recommend. Here is the documentation for the verification results API https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker/blob/master/lib/pact_broker/doc/views/publish-verification-results.markdown Note that you want to publish both successes and failures, so if you put this in a separate process beware of the fact that a lot of builds/scripts will stop on error. You also want to publish the results per pact, so if you're verifying multiple pacts, the failure of one should not cause the other to fail.

Comment: Part 2, ran out of characters. For the reason I just mentioned, a proper implementation would require that the publishing code is part of the verification runner itself, as it needs the results of the individual pact verifications, not the overall result. However, if you're just verifying one pact as a POC, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

When verfying pact ensure you have the value publishVerificationResult: true as an option in order for the pact to be published.